# Helicopters problem: What is the probability of being heard but not seen?

Tags: probability, geometry

> Consider an observer who can hear helicopters at a distance of $s$ and can see helicopters at a distance of $r$. Let $s \geq r$ and fix $s = 1$.
>
> Given an observer can hear a helicopter flying in a straight path over them, determine a probability function $P(r)$ that an observer *cannot* see the helicopter.

My current solution:

We only consider helicopters that enter the audible radius, so we can define any path from the edge of the outer circle with radius `s` through the circle. A tangent line to this circle is the boundary for a helicopter which enters the audible range.

We define `θout` as the angle between a tangent of the outer circle (the audible range) and a tangent of the inner circle (the visible range) extending from the same point on the outer circle. This is the angle where helicopters are heard, but not seen.

We define `θin` as the angle where helicopters are both heard and seen.

Hence, our probability that a line goes through the audible range, but *not* the visible range is:

$P(r) = \frac{θout}{θout + θin}$

By symmetry, we can focus only on a quarter of the circle. So we have:

$θout + θin = \frac{π}{2}$.

We can also see from the geometry that:

$θin = sin^{-1}(r)$

Finally, we can represent `θout` in terms of `r`, and solve accordingly.

$P(r) = \frac{\frac{π}{2} - sin^{-1}(r)}{\frac{π}{2}}$

$P(r) = 1 - \frac{2}{π}sin^{-1}(r)$

[Diagram of solution geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2zgo.png)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The problem is poorly phrased. Where I live, it's very unlikely that I can see or hear a helicopter at a random time on any given day. They probably mean to ask for the probability that you can't see a helicopter *given* that you can hear it, assuming its location is uniformly randomly distributed in the circular region where you can hear it. Have you tried drawing a picture of the situation?

Comment: @Karl you're right about the wording. I changed it to clarify, and added my proposed solution with a diagram.

Comment: I don't see why you need to do any trig. I think you are overthinking it The plane is a single distance $w$ with $0\le w \le s$.  You are just asked the probability that $w > r$ which, if we assume normal distributions (which can argue about) is simply $\frac {s-r}s$

Comment: The problem certainly has many interpretations. I get $1-\frac{r^2}{s^2}$ by comparing the areas of two circles.

Comment: Even though the diagram is in 2D (same for many PNG images), but since the helicopter from the question is "flying in a straight path over them", maybe you should consider its altitude too.

Comment: Make it a bit more complicated: I only start looking for helicopters when I hear one. Taking into account the speed of sound, what is the probability that I can spot one if I start looking when I hear it?

Comment: Good point @peterwhy. I think solving the 2D case makes sense for now, and extending the solution to an extra dimension should follow fairly easily from it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is similar to [Bertrand paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)), in which an ill-posed problem has different answers of $\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{1}{4}$, and $\frac{1}{2}$, depending on how uniform selection is defined based on three selection methods of random endpoint, random midpoint, and random radius (radial point).

Here, similarly you can have different solutions.

1. Your answer is the same as the endpoint method. It hiddenly assumes that the person is always there and can always hear when any helicopter enters the first circle.
2. The answer $$1-\frac{r^2}{s^2}$$ obtained by dividing the areas is related to the midpoint method. It hiddenly assumes that the person happens to be in a position to hear the sound of a helicopter entering the first circle, which depends on the position of the helicopter, not obly its distance from the person.
3. If you use the radius method, the answer is  $$1-\frac{r}{s}.$$ Here, it is hiddenly assumed that the person happens to be in a position to hear the sound of a helicopter entering the first circle, which depends only on the distance of the helicopter from the person.

---

A more accurate approch to solve the problem under the third case may be to assume that the person is at the origin $(0,0)$ and we know the joint distribution $f(x,y)$ of the location of a flying helicopter at a time instant (this can be time dependent, and multiple ones can fly, but let us make it simple). Then, the probabilty of that a person *who happens to check outside* hears a helicoper but cannot see it is given by

$$\mathbb P \left ( r<\sqrt{X^2+Y^2} <s \right ), $$

in which I used the third method.

Now assume the person stays out for $\Delta t $ amount of time, the speed of a helicopter is $v$, and its fligth direction is the normalized (constant or random) direction $(D_1, D_2)$, then the probability is given by

$$\mathbb P \left ( R(0)>r, R(t) \in (r,s) \, \text{for some} \, t \in (0,\Delta t) \right ) $$

where

$$R(t)=\sqrt{(X+vD_1 t)^2+(Y+vD_2 t)^2}.$$

Comment: This is really interesting - thanks for pointing it out! I suppose a more concrete formulation of the problem would say it's given that the observer can hear the helicopter entering the audible radius, not just that they can hear it at all.

Comment: @user2566536 you are welcome! Just added another modeling approch, which seems more applied.